# Dapper QuerySingleOrDefault returns an error

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I'm using dapper to get data based on a username so according to the documentation I have wrote something like that:

```
Data data= conn.QuerySingleOrDefault<Data>("select * from table_name where username=@username",new  { username= new DbString { Value = "John1234", IsFixedLength = true, Length = 255, IsAnsi = true } });
```

now the problem is dapper returns: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. what can be the problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```cs
    Data data = conn.QuerySingleOrDefault<Data>("select * from table_name where username=@username", new { username= "John1234" });
```

Comment: yes it didn't work turns out that the string value that Dapper was complaining about was inside the class/json model itself so username was int but expected to fetch the data to a string that's why the error happened ,the class blueprint was long so I didn't notice that
thanks anyway @Nowlights